# why clk_o2 is x here?

Tags: verilog, gtkwave

I've tried to delay in the initial but it doesn't work
I'm a newbie in Verilog and it was a training problem

[The ClockDivisor Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGoEH.png)

[The Test bensh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRoVA.png)

[The Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gauI9.png)

I get x at clk_o2 if I change it on the negative edge

Comment: It would really help to post your code directly in the question instead of linking to a screenshot of it. That makes it easier to try it ourselves and refer to it while answering. Also, it's a struggle to find what you mean by *change it on the negative edge*.

Comment: For some reason, I don't know 
when I tried to post code, the system refuses and tell me to format my code :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are referring to the last always block in the clkdivisor module. The problem is your testbench produces a `negedge clk` at time 0 because it code from X to 0. That creates a race with the `initial` block trying to assign clockout2 to 0.

You can get rid of the race by using a blocking assignment.
initial begin
    clockout1 = 0;
    clockout2 = 0;
end

Your code is certainly not synthesizable. There are other ways of fixing this, but we don't know exactly what is supposed to do.